# NSViewController and bindings

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my application I have a single nib file. The `File's Owner` is a `NSViewController` and insider there is just a vertical slider that I want to bind to a property in one of my classes. (I don't have any other nib files since it is a status bar application, so I don't have a window). The nib is loaded runtime to create a custom view for a `NSMenuItem`.

The problem is that I want to use an object controller to do the binding but I'm not sure what is the content of the object controller. How can I access from the nib to an arbitrary class in my project?

In the examples I have seen, usually the object controller uses the `File's Owner` to access the class (and the property for the binding) setting the Content Object binding to the File's Owner. But in my case from the File's Owner I do not have access to the class.

Any pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this works for me. It is enough subclassing `NSViewController` and sets the new subclass as the `File's Owner`. Now it is possible to use a `Controller Object` to bind through the `File's Owner`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use XCode 4 you can <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from the slider to the .h file (AppController.h?), and you will get the option to generate an outlet or an action. If you want to create an action, caused by sliding the slider, you should select action. The generated method will be called whenever the slider is changed. If you want the slider value to react to an event (or a changed instance variable in your program), set it to 'outlet'.
Hope that helps, let me know if you were really looking for something else :-)

Comment: Well, actually I want to use bindings to do that without outlets and actions. I have found this very interesting [post](http://crazyviraj.blogspot.com/2009/05/cocoa-what-is-files-owner-in-nib.html). It seems that the better solution is subclassing the NSViewController and bind using the File's Owner.

Comment: I see, and you're right. My "solution" would not work in that case! Your solution seems like it should work. However, I am curious why you prefer a subclass, but would rather not use outlets and action.

Comment: I need to connect a vertical slider to a volume property in my program. I think that using bindings is the most correct way (but it is also possible to use outlets and actions, of course).

Comment: BTW the first example [here](http://homepage.mac.com/mmalc/CocoaExamples/controllers.html) is really useful to understand bindings.